# Refine Colorview Code

Tags: c++, adafruit

How would I refine this to only recognize red and green? I don't need the full functionality of this code, just the ability to distinguish between red and green, and output that respectively.

I also would like to eliminate the bleed over; meaning, the green led stays on slightly when I flood the Adafruit with red light and vice versa. I am not really familiar with the output of the Adafruit, but it seems this could be an analog "question and answer" situation; it's either green or red or nothing.

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include "Adafruit_TCS34725.h"

#ifndef _TCS34725_H_
#define _TCS34725_H_

#if ARDUINO >= 100
 #include <Arduino.h>
#else
 #include <WProgram.h>
#endif

#include <Wire.h>

#define TCS34725_ADDRESS          (0x29)

#define TCS34725_COMMAND_BIT      (0x80)

#define TCS34725_ENABLE           (0x00)
#define TCS34725_ENABLE_AIEN      (0x10)    /* RGBC Interrupt Enable */
#define TCS34725_ENABLE_WEN       (0x08)    /* Wait enable - Writing 1 activates the wait timer */
#define TCS34725_ENABLE_AEN       (0x02)    /* RGBC Enable - Writing 1 actives the ADC, 0 disables it */
#define TCS34725_ENABLE_PON       (0x01)    /* Power on - Writing 1 activates the internal oscillator, 0 disables it */
#define TCS34725_ATIME            (0x01)    /* Integration time */
#define TCS34725_WTIME            (0x03)    /* Wait time (if TCS34725_ENABLE_WEN is asserted) */
#define TCS34725_WTIME_2_4MS      (0xFF)    /* WLONG0 = 2.4ms   WLONG1 = 0.029s */
#define TCS34725_WTIME_204MS      (0xAB)    /* WLONG0 = 204ms   WLONG1 = 2.45s  */
#define TCS34725_WTIME_614MS      (0x00)    /* WLONG0 = 614ms   WLONG1 = 7.4s   */
#define TCS34725_AILTL            (0x04)    /* Clear channel lower interrupt threshold */
#define TCS34725_AILTH            (0x05)
#define TCS34725_AIHTL            (0x06)    /* Clear channel upper interrupt threshold */
#define TCS34725_AIHTH            (0x07)
#define TCS34725_PERS             (0x0C)    /* Persistence register - basic SW filtering mechanism for interrupts */
#define TCS34725_PERS_NONE        (0b0000)  /* Every RGBC cycle generates an interrupt                                */
#define TCS34725_PERS_1_CYCLE     (0b0001)  /* 1 clean channel value outside threshold range generates an interrupt   */
#define TCS34725_PERS_2_CYCLE     (0b0010)  /* 2 clean channel values outside threshold range generates an interrupt  */
#define TCS34725_PERS_3_CYCLE     (0b0011)  /* 3 clean channel values outside threshold range generates an interrupt  */
#define TCS34725_PERS_5_CYCLE     (0b0100)  /* 5 clean channel values outside threshold range generates an interrupt  */
#define TCS34725_PERS_10_CYCLE    (0b0101)  /* 10 clean channel values outside threshold range generates an interrupt */
#define TCS34725_PERS_15_CYCLE    (0b0110)  /* 15 clean channel values outside threshold range generates an interrupt */
#define TCS34725_PERS_20_CYCLE    (0b0111)  /* 20 clean channel values outside threshold range generates an interrupt */
#define TCS34725_PERS_25_CYCLE    (0b1000)  /* 25 clean channel values outside threshold range generates an interrupt */
#define TCS34725_PERS_30_CYCLE    (0b1001)  /* 30 clean channel values outside threshold range generates an interrupt */
#define TCS34725_PERS_35_CYCLE    (0b1010)  /* 35 clean channel values outside threshold range generates an interrupt */
#define TCS34725_PERS_40_CYCLE    (0b1011)  /* 40 clean channel values outside threshold range generates an interrupt */
#define TCS34725_PERS_45_CYCLE    (0b1100)  /* 45 clean channel values outside threshold range generates an interrupt */
#define TCS34725_PERS_50_CYCLE    (0b1101)  /* 50 clean channel values outside threshold range generates an interrupt */
#define TCS34725_PERS_55_CYCLE    (0b1110)  /* 55 clean channel values outside threshold range generates an interrupt */
#define TCS34725_PERS_60_CYCLE    (0b1111)  /* 60 clean channel values outside threshold range generates an interrupt */
#define TCS34725_CONFIG           (0x0D)
#define TCS34725_CONFIG_WLONG     (0x02)    /* Choose between short and long (12x) wait times via TCS34725_WTIME */
#define TCS34725_CONTROL          (0x0F)    /* Set the gain level for the sensor */
#define TCS34725_ID               (0x12)    /* 0x44 = TCS34721/TCS34725, 0x4D = TCS34723/TCS34727 */
#define TCS34725_STATUS           (0x13)
#define TCS34725_STATUS_AINT      (0x10)    /* RGBC Clean channel interrupt */
#define TCS34725_STATUS_AVALID    (0x01)    /* Indicates that the RGBC channels have completed an integration cycle */
#define TCS34725_CDATAL           (0x14)    /* Clear channel data */
#define TCS34725_CDATAH           (0x15)
#define TCS34725_RDATAL           (0x16)    /* Red channel data */
#define TCS34725_RDATAH           (0x17)
#define TCS34725_GDATAL           (0x18)    /* Green channel data */
#define TCS34725_GDATAH           (0x19)
#define TCS34725_BDATAL           (0x1A)    /* Blue channel data */
#define TCS34725_BDATAH           (0x1B)

typedef enum
{
  TCS34725_INTEGRATIONTIME_2_4MS  = 0xFF,   /**<  2.4ms - 1 cycle    - Max Count: 1024  */
  TCS34725_INTEGRATIONTIME_24MS   = 0xF6,   /**<  24ms  - 10 cycles  - Max Count: 10240 */
  TCS34725_INTEGRATIONTIME_50MS   = 0xEB,   /**<  50ms  - 20 cycles  - Max Count: 20480 */
  TCS34725_INTEGRATIONTIME_101MS  = 0xD5,   /**<  101ms - 42 cycles  - Max Count: 43008 */
  TCS34725_INTEGRATIONTIME_154MS  = 0xC0,   /**<  154ms - 64 cycles  - Max Count: 65535 */
  TCS34725_INTEGRATIONTIME_700MS  = 0x00    /**<  700ms - 256 cycles - Max Count: 65535 */
}
tcs34725IntegrationTime_t;

typedef enum
{
  TCS34725_GAIN_1X                = 0x00,   /**<  No gain  */
  TCS34725_GAIN_4X                = 0x01,   /**<  4x gain  */
  TCS34725_GAIN_16X               = 0x02,   /**<  16x gain */
  TCS34725_GAIN_60X               = 0x03    /**<  60x gain */
}
tcs34725Gain_t;

class Adafruit_TCS34725 {
 public:
  Adafruit_TCS34725(tcs34725IntegrationTime_t = TCS34725_INTEGRATIONTIME_2_4MS, tcs34725Gain_t = TCS34725_GAIN_1X);

  boolean  begin(void);
  void     setIntegrationTime(tcs34725IntegrationTime_t it);
  void     setGain(tcs34725Gain_t gain);
  void     getRawData(uint16_t *r, uint16_t *g, uint16_t *b, uint16_t *c);
  uint16_t calculateColorTemperature(uint16_t r, uint16_t g, uint16_t b);
  uint16_t calculateLux(uint16_t r, uint16_t g, uint16_t b);
  void     write8 (uint8_t reg, uint32_t value);
  uint8_t  read8 (uint8_t reg);
  uint16_t read16 (uint8_t reg);
  void setInterrupt(boolean flag);
  void clearInterrupt(void);
  void setIntLimits(uint16_t l, uint16_t h);
  void     enable(void);

 private:
  boolean _tcs34725Initialised;
  tcs34725Gain_t _tcs34725Gain;
  tcs34725IntegrationTime_t _tcs34725IntegrationTime; 

  void     disable(void);
};

#endif

// Pick analog outputs, for the UNO these three work well
// use ~560  ohm resistor between Red & Blue, ~1K for green (its brighter)
#define redpin 3
#define greenpin 5
#define bluepin 6
// for a common anode LED, connect the common pin to +5V
// for common cathode, connect the common to ground

// set to false if using a common cathode LED
#define commonAnode true

// our RGB -> eye-recognized gamma color
byte gammatable[256];


Adafruit_TCS34725 tcs = Adafruit_TCS34725(TCS34725_INTEGRATIONTIME_50MS, TCS34725_GAIN_4X);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Color View Test!");

  if (tcs.begin()) {
    Serial.println("Found sensor");
  } else {
    Serial.println("No TCS34725 found ... check your connections");
    while (1); // halt!
  }

  // use these three pins to drive an LED
  pinMode(redpin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(greenpin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(bluepin, OUTPUT);

  // thanks PhilB for this gamma table!
  // it helps convert RGB colors to what humans see
  for (int i=0; i<256; i++) {
    float x = i;
    x /= 255;
    x = pow(x, 2.5);
    x *= 255;

    if (commonAnode) {
      gammatable[i] = 255 - x;
    } else {
      gammatable[i] = x;      
    }
    //Serial.println(gammatable[i]);
  }
}


void loop() {
  uint16_t clear, red, green, blue;

  tcs.setInterrupt(false);      // turn on LED

  delay(60);  // takes 50ms to read 

  tcs.getRawData(&red, &green, &blue, &clear);

  tcs.setInterrupt(true);  // turn off LED

  Serial.print("C:\t"); Serial.print(clear);
  Serial.print("\tR:\t"); Serial.print(red);
  Serial.print("\tG:\t"); Serial.print(green);
  Serial.print("\tB:\t"); Serial.print(blue);

  // Figure out some basic hex code for visualization
  uint32_t sum = clear;
  float r, g, b;
  r = red; r /= sum;
  g = green; g /= sum;
  b = blue; b /= sum;
  r *= 256; g *= 256; b *= 256;
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print((int)r, HEX); Serial.print((int)g, HEX); Serial.print((int)b, HEX);
  Serial.println();

  //Serial.print((int)r ); Serial.print(" "); Serial.print((int)g);Serial.print(" ");  Serial.println((int)b );

  analogWrite(redpin, gammatable[(int)r]);
  analogWrite(greenpin, gammatable[(int)g]);
  analogWrite(bluepin, gammatable[(int)b]);
```